# Return count of days in month using array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, array

I have a range of dates in a column as such:

```
01/03/2017
31/04/2017
06/05/2017
...
```

It is required to count the number of days which fall in a certain month, say April. I believe this is possible by using the MONTH formula with array formulae to return an array of months to COUNTIF, using the format below:

```
=COUNTIF(month(G15:G17),4)
```

Entered as an array formula using CTRL & SHIFT & ENTER.

However EXCEL thinks I'm not trying to write or formulua or that my formula is wrong. Upon entering the formula, EXCEL returns this message:

[image]

What is the error in my formula or my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use a combination of `SUM()` and `IF()` as seen below:

`=SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A4)=4,1,0))`

Enter as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll see the curly braces in the formula bar like this:

`{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A4)=4,1,0))}`

Comment: ... without entering the curly braces.  `{` and `}`

Comment: `=COUNTIF(MONTH(A1:A4),12)` does not need to be entered as array formula

Comment: @Hannu Thanks for the clarification. I edited my answer regarding the braces. `=COUNTIF(MONTH(A1:A4),12)` as a non-array formula gives *The formula you typed contains an error* on Excel 2013.

Comment: Hmm... Using LibreOffice Calc here, I currently have no Excel to try it with - maybe `=COUNTIF(MONTH(A1:A4),"="&12)` will work in Excel?

Comment: @Hannu, I get *The formula you typed contains an error* whether or nor it's entered as an array formula in Excel 2011 (Mac).  Anyone, why doesn't the OP's formula work?  F9 shows the MONTH() portion returns an array of the month numbers, and using INDEX() to return an array for the first part of a COUNTIF() works fine, too.

Comment: @Hannu That still gives the same error. Google Sheets does not give an error, but does not report the correct results unless `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(MONTH(A1:A4),4))` is used (or `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A7)=4,1,0)))`

Comment: ...and "="&12 makes no difference either.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(G15:G17)=4))`